# Redshift - Split column to find value between delimiter with uncertain position

Tags: database, string, split, amazon-redshift

I have a table in redshift with two columns, id and link.

***Current Table***

### id                link

1         www.something.com/bla?lughlegh **&fruit=apple&** khkhflkjndkj&ljghldh&ljhrleh

2         www.somethingelse.com/blabla?sdf&hthdth&sdhfhfY **&fruit=orange&** ergegertg

I want to pick the value fruit=apple from the link column. But the catch is -

- &fruit=apple& can appear anywhere in the link [In first link fruit is between 1st and 2nd & symbol. But, in second link, fruit is between 3rd and 4th & symbol.]
- There are many &. So I cannot say that I always want the value between 3rd and 4th & symbol.
- Number of & symbols in the link is not always constant
- The value of fruit can be anything (not apple always)

I have to basically look for the text **fruit=** and pick values between fruit= and the next &

***Required table***

### id                link                                           ***fruit***

1         www.something.com/bla?lughlegh **&fruit=apple&** khkhflkjndkj&ljghldh&ljhrleh                                      ***apple***

2         www.somethingelse.com/blabla?sdf&hthdth&sdhfhfY **&fruit=orange&** ergegertg                                                         ***orange***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_REPLACE.html):

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(url, ".*[?&]fruit=([^&]*).*", "$1");
```